# Get Facebook UID in page tab without asking for permission

Tags: php, facebook

I'm developing a **Facebook app** for a tab but I encountered the problem. I can't get the **Facebook UID** from the user is seeing my tab.

I'm working on a **poll system** and I would like to use a personal voting system since I cannot use Facebook likes to achieve this.

The users should only be able to vote once per Facebook account.

Is there a way to have the track of user votes this way?

Thanks <3

Comment: you will need to have the user login to your app first (is this what you're looking for? if yes, i'll write you a block of code)

Answer (score 1):

Im having the same problem here. I think the only two ways to achieve this is to:

1. Ask for authorization for the voting users
2. Use another voting paradigm

This could be using user ip or cookies.

I know im not solving your problem, but as far as my research reached, theres no way to achieve that now!

Comment: i can write the code, but it requires making the user login to the app.

Comment: @Tets Tets is correct. You must allow them to authorize your app before you can get a Facebook UserId. You can ask for any permission such as user_about_me to get the UserId.