# Distinguish facebook users without asking for permission

Tags: facebook

Within a facebook app, is there a reliable way ensure, that a given action can only be performed once per facebook user, without asking the user to authorize the app?

From the looks of the documentation and the lack of positive responses to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900437/get-facebook-uid-in-page-tab-without-asking-for-permission) I would deduce it's impossible, but I have been told the adverse - without actual details.

So what I need to know:

- Is there any way to achieve this?

  or (if not):
- Is there any resource that clearly states that this is impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you give a more detailed example of what you are trying to do and which language you are trying to do it in?

If you have the ability to access the user_id through an indexable field like you have in a  friend, like or event relationship, you could just store the user_ids in your own database as they take actions in your page. If they've already performed the action once, you'd just give a message to the user and drop whatever action just occurred. You can find all the indexable fields in the fql documentation.

If you want to get the id from a random user who happens across your app, they need to authorize your app before you can get access to their information.

I've seen a few scam apps on FB that manage to get user permissions as soon as a logged in user visits their page. These violate the TOS and most likely get deleted and their admin banned as soon as they are reported.

Comment: `If you want to get the id from a random user who happens across your app, they need to authorize your app before you can get access to their information.` That's what my question is all about. Do you have any reference to where this is made clear. Or maybe you could even point me to the section in the TOS that says procuring the user_id otherwise is a violation?

Comment: I think this gets covered by section I.3 in the platform policies: "You must not circumvent our intended limitations on core Facebook features and functionality." https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#policies

Comment: This might also be covered by I.7.a: " When a user visits your Page, if they have not given explicit permission by authorizing your Facebook app or directly providing information to your Page, you may only use information obtained from us and the user's interaction with your Page in connection with that Page."